# Is there any solution for this memory issue?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, data-science, data-mining, data-analysis

**Salam all...**

I have analyzed a big dataset of tweets with python in windows operating system.. when i try to transform the data to vectors (tfidf) it gives me this error message:

**MemoryError unable to allocate 298. Gib for an array with shape (439563, 90889) and data type float64**

How I can solve this problem?

the following is the used code:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform("MyData")
tf_idf = pd.DataFrame(data = X.toarray(), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
final_df = tf_idf
print("{} rows".format(final_df.shape[0]))
final_df.T.nlargest(5, 0)
```

Comment: The solution is to not read everything into memory at once, or buy (a lot) more RAM. If you provide some code, someone can give you help that is more specific

Comment: Since you're only looking for the number of rows and the largest 5 values, you can use an iterator to go over the `TfidfVectorizer` and collect the top 5 as you go, instead of computing and collecting everything into an array and only then taking the 5 largest from the whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com)

 you can access to a strong GPU & RAM for free

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to divide the data into small size files then process it separately .. I did it and i got my desired result .. thank you for all ..